# How to connect peripheral/ BLE device by using identifier?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to connect the peripheral by using an identifier.
Can I do it?

```
centralManager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
```

I am scanning devices in one `ViewController` and Connecting it in another `ViewController`.

**Below is my requirement:**

When I scanned device and saved the next time the device that can appear in home screen and directly connected.
So for this, I use singleton class to access peripheral data from one view to another view. But it always initializes to empty.
So I want to connect peripheral by using an identifier. 
I don't know where we store `[CBPeripheral]` and access it when needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I want to connect the peripheral by using an identifier. Can I do it?**

**Short answer:** 
NO, You can't do it.

**Long answer:**

[Refer apple official document.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518766-connect)

> There are no provision or method which is used to connect with an
>   identifier But, Apple has provision to retrieve peripherals by using
>   the identifier.

**Let's discuss some other alternatives**

The `CBPeripheral` does not implement NSCoding. So, it is next to impossible to store `BLEPeripheral` object into `NSUserDefaults` OR any other container.

The best solution is to store the properties of `CBPeripheral` like name or identifier etc.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Device_name, forKey: "Device_name")
UserDefaults.standard.set(Device_Identifier forKey: "Device_Identifier")
```

By using `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)` you can get `BLEPeripheral` value again. Then you can connect directly using this object

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1519127-retrieveperipherals)

**retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)**

> Returns a list of known peripherals by their identifiers.